# Gallery images overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a list of images in 4 rows and 2 columns.  I have checked my CSS pretty carefully, but I can't seems to not have the image in the right column overlap the image on the left.  That leaves the `li`, the `li p` and `li p a` elemens all out of what too.  I tried to create some space in between the columns by narrowing the width to 45% and having a margin on 2.5% on all sides, but no luck.  Any suggestions?

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <section>
          <ul id="gallery">
            <li>
              <a href = "img/image1.jpg">
               <img src = "img/image1.jpg" alt="">
               <p>Caption here</p>
               </a>
             </li>

            <li>
              ...
            </li>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body{

    font-family: 'Open Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #5F5E5E;
 }

     #gallery{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
     }

     #gallery li{
      float: left;
      width: 45%;
      margin: 2.5%;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      color: #bdc3c7;
    }

    #gallery li a p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 5%;
      font-size: 0.75em;
      color: #bdc3c7;
     }
```

Comment: Can you post your exact html and maybe put a fiddle together?

Comment: Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/5f7k1jnt/  Not a great orientation of how it's displaying, but every image is 415 x 279 px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your images are overflowing their container (*the `a`*).

Try adding

```
#gallery li a{display:block}
#gallery li img{width:100%;}
```

This way images will always fit their container.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body{

    font-family: 'Open Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #5F5E5E;
 }

     #gallery{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
     }

     #gallery li{
      float: left;
      width: 45%;
      margin: 2.5%;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      color: #bdc3c7;
    }

    #gallery li a p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 5%;
      font-size: 0.75em;
      color: #bdc3c7;
     }
#gallery li a{display:block}
#gallery li img{width:100%;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <section>
        <ul id="gallery">
            <li>
                <a href = "img/image1.jpg">
                    <img src = "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/fashion/1" alt="" />
                    <p>Caption here</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href = "img/image1.jpg">
                    <img src = "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/fashion/2" alt="" />
                    <p>Caption here</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href = "img/image1.jpg">
                    <img src = "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/fashion/4" alt="" />
                    <p>Caption here</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code little bit like the following. It works for me.
Let me know if it works for you.

```
<style>

 *{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
```

}

body{

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
max-width: 100%;
background-color: #5F5E5E;
```

}

```
.box{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  margin: 10px 0.5% 0px 0px;
  background: #dd8;
  border-radius: 7px;
 }

 .innerbox{
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
right: 10px;
left: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
}


.innerbox img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="innerbox">
            <img src="image1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="title">Title here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="innerbox">
            <img src="image2.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="title">Title here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```